# How to generate Work order PDF in YII

Tags: php, pdf-generation, yii-extensions

I'm new to yii. I need to generate PDF work order form in yii.
I have tried many extensions but they are not working in right way. Here I attach a sample image of my desired Work order form. Which plugin is suitable for generate a PDF with this format.[image]

Comment: Define "not working in right way"?

Comment: There are extensions that allow you to generate pdfs from html, so just generate that form in html and then just use the extension to convert it to a pdf.